# UINavigationBar or statusBarHeight -> 0 when CGAffineTransform applied to viewController.view

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uikit, cgaffinetransform, safearealayoutguide, uiviewpropertyanimator

I am writing an interactive transition via `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`. As part of the transition, I apply a `CGAffineTransform` to the `from view controller`.

As soon as the transform is applied, fromViewController loses its safeAreaInset at the top. This looks jarring.

Here is a pic just before the transition starts. Normal status bar, navigation bar, and safe area insets (top). Around 88 points high. 
[image: Standard status bar and nav bar]

This is the first frame of the transition. Notice that the top spacing is now more like 44 points. 
[image]

The fromVC remains this way all the way through the transition. I have tried different ways of applying the transforms, but they all behave the same way. I have also removed the rounded corners.

Here are the transforms:

```
var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            transform.concatenating(CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: 0, y: yInset / 2))
            transform.concatenating(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: scaleX, y: scaleY))

fromVC.view.transform = transform
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up solving this was to use `CATransform3D` instead of `CGAffineTransform`. The padding remains in place with this technique.

```
let scale = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, scaleX, scaleY, 1)
let translate = CATransform3DTranslate(scale, 0, yInset / 2, 0)
return CATransform3DConcat(scale, translate)
```

[image]